# Unlock phone with adb without text or keyevent input

Tags: adb, lock-screens, hardware

Is there a way to unlock an Android phone with `adb` using `adb shell` without a keyevent input?

Comment: That is screen mirroring, not an Android shell command

Comment: android has smart lock feature. never used but afair it can unlock device. if you authorize the right trigger which can be activated by adb commands, it might work. maybe there is partially solution on android enthusiasts already, do a research